# VSTS Release slack integration display release name

Tags: slack, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I setup a Service Hook in VSTS to Slack. It will post to Slack when a release deployment has completed. This is working correctly and the image below shows the post. However, it doesn't include the release definition name. We have alot of release definitions setup to deploy our apps. Without the release name we can't tell which release this was for. Is there anyway to include the release definition name in the slack post?

[image]

Comment: As Daniel said that you can include release definition name in release name, open release definition > General > Release-$(rev:r)-$(Release.DefinitionName)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include the release definition name in the release name.

Comment: I changed the release name to Release-$(rev:r)-$(Release.DefinitionName) and that solved the problem.